# Get tweet list of VIP by using their username

Tags: android, ios, twitter

Hi have to show a page whit a list of tweet of some VIP peoples.
Is there a way by using tweet API to get a request passing multiple username and get back the list of tweet ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps i have found:

Create an account

1. on twitter and follow the VIP's that you wish to stream
2. register your application on twitter https://apps.twitter.com/
3. use the OAuth tool to get the signature for the request
   https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/user#oauth-tool
4. follow the API link to access the json file via http request
   https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/user
5. URL will be something like this
   https://userstream.twitter.com/1.1/user.json
6. Parse the JSON returned and then display within your app.